# VB.Net Function overload resolution issue in VS2017

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

while migrating the vb.net project from VS2010 to VS 2017 we are getting missing reference error due to incorrect function overload resolution

JS
 **************************Project 1 *******************************

```
Imports Microsoft.Practices
Imports Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data
Public MustInherit Class DataLayerSQLBase
    Private m_factory As EnterpriseLibrary.Data.DatabaseProviderFactory
    Private m_database As Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database
    Public Function ExecuteReader(ByVal spName As String) As IDataReader
        m_database = m_factory.CreateDefault
        Return ExecuteReader(m_database, spName)
    End Function
    Public Function ExecuteReader(ByVal spName As String, ByVal secondparam As String) As IDataReader
        m_database = m_factory.CreateDefault
        Return ExecuteReader(m_database, spName)
    End Function
    Public Function ExecuteReader(ByVal database As EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database, ByVal spName As String) As IDataReader
        Dim m_Command = database.GetStoredProcCommand(spName)
        m_Command.CommandTimeout = 300
        Return m_Command.ExecuteReader
    End Function

End Class
```

**************************Project 1 *******************************
 **************************Project 2 *******************************

This project refers project 1 and doesn't have Enterprise.Library.Data.dll reference, this fails to compile in VS2017 asking for adding reference but works in VS2010 without adding reference

```
Imports ClassLibrary1
Public Class Class3
    Inherits DataLayerSQLBase
    Public Sub Test()
        MyBase.ExecuteReader("aaaa", "aaaaa")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: So, you're claiming that a VB 2010 project can make use of the Enterprise Library without referencing it but a VB 2017 project can't? I don't see how that could possibly be the case. How could the VB 2010 project even know that the Enterprise Library exists if it's not referenced?

Comment: issue is project 2 refers project 1 and calls overload which doesn't require enterprise library specific object as parameter.  This works fine in VS2010, but VS2017 asks for the reference even though that overload is not called.